# No split apks compatible with Android emulator

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have an NDK project where I am building for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, and x86. Runnning the code on a phone works fine, but trying to run on an x86 emulator builds properly, but then gives the following error:

`The currently selected variant "debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "560" and ABIs "x86".`

Initially, I tried to avoid using split apks by doing the following in my build.gradle:

```
splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
    density {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
        enable false
    }

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI
    abi {
        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true

        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, and x86

        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'

        // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

But re-reading the error, it says none of the 1 split APKs. There's only 1 APK generated and it's incompatible, so I guess the wrong one is being generated? What tools could I use to dig deeper?

Answer (score 3):

You try this way

```
  include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
```

and try to set

```
universalApk false
```

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issue while running minos-mobile app on MacBook M1 Pro.

```
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: The currently selected variant "debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with ABIs "arm64-v8a".
```

I added the APK Split Configuration in build.gradle file

```
android {
 
 ....

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}

project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                        com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of not including x86 in my list of abi splits upon closer inspection.